# Public couchdb security

Tags: apache, security, https, couchdb

I exposed a couchdb on `https://db.example.com` then my services can directly request this URL.

However everyone can access to the DB UI at `https://db.example.com/_utils`. Or simply request the DB.

Is there a protection against brute force like rate limit or IP blacklist?
Is there any solution for a public couchdb?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful links to the docs for handling security within CouchDB

- http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html
- http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#httpd/bind_address

It can help you whether you only allow certain IP(s) to access the database or create users that your services can use to access CouchDB.